# Data.SE Still calls us "gaming"

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

While [querying Arqade](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/new) on data.SE, I noticed that the page title still says `Query Gaming`. Out of curiosity, I popped over and opened a [query of SU](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new) and saw that the page title was `Query Super User`.

Though arqade.com does redirect to gaming.se, I see this as being inconsistent with our rebranding as Arqade.  It doesn't seem to be an Arqade-only bug, though. Ask Different has the [same inconsistency](http://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/new).

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, the site metadata has to be updated manually, so it occasionally falls out of date. I'll send Nick some corrections to run when he has the time and then everything should be good.

Comment: If I do this as-is, it'll break URLs, so hmmmmm

Comment: My thought was to only update the `LongName`, we can leave the shorter name used in the URLs as-is.

Comment: Fair point, updated gaming and apple descriptions - we are ordering more drive space for the SO import, it went boom this weekend due to growth....oops.

Comment: Thanks! Whoops, heh. Supposed it was only a matter of time.

Comment: [Ordered!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVn1oQL9sWg)

Comment: Dad, are you space?